# nginx ignores view permissions when serving media files from django

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, uwsgi

I have the following setup:

## nginx.conf

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/project.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        internal;
        root /Users/halsdunes/Desktop/project/backend;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        root /Users/halsdunes/Desktop/project/backend; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /Users/halsdunes/Desktop/project/backend/backend/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

## directmessages/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from directmessages.views import message_image_serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^message_images/user_(?P<user1_id>\d+)/user_(?P<user2_id>\d+)/(?P<uuid>[0-9a-f-]+).jpg$', message_image_serve, name='message_image_service'),
]
```

with the root `url.py` like this:

```
url(r'^media/', include('directmessages.urls')),
```

## directmessages/views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def message_image_serve(request, user1_id, user2_id, uuid):

    user_id = request.user.id

    if not user_id in (int(user1_id), int(user2_id)):
        raise Http404

    path = 'message_images/user_%s/user_%s/%s.jpg' % (user1_id, user2_id, uuid)

    response = serve(request, path, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = safe_join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)

    return response
```

My assumption is that because of the configuration, nginx is bypassing the Django view entirely and serving up the image. However, this isn't quite what I want. In reality, I'd rather if it:

- Checked the django view to make sure that the permissions are correct
- Have nginx serve the actual image file if the validation passes

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to give that view a different URL, which is *not* captured by nginx's media serving. Django will then respond with the X-Accel-Redirect header which will cause nginx to serve the file in the response.

Comment: Could you explain which part is being captured by nginx, I'm not completely clear on what kind of different url you're mentioning?

Comment: Anything under /media is served by the nginx directive for that path and is therefore not passed on to Django, so your media URL in Django is never used. Change one of them.

Comment: I changed the `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py` to '/uploads/' and kept the `MEDIA_ROOT` as `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`, as well and made the corresponding edits to the root `urls.py`. Now I'm getting a 404 where the request url is `http://localhost:8000/Users/halsdunes/Desktop/project/backend/media/profile_images/user_1/340e42f5-f9f8-4b3b-bada-78a43b725028.jpg`, which seems incorrect. Any thoughts on this? Works fine when I run the server using `manage.py runserver` but no dice on nginx/uWSGI.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I am having the same issue

Comment: beware. for me the main pitfall were the nuances with alias/root and trailing slashes! see here: nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile - one must really concentrate to not make any mistakes!